# IsPostBack always returns false

Tags: asp.net, postback, session-state, asp.net-4.0, ispostback

I've encountered a weird problem. Everytime I refresh the page, `IsPostBack` is false.
To make sure nothing in my contents or master pages is causing this, I have created an empty web form and fired it up in debug mode. still, on postbacks, I have `IsPostBack` set to false.

I have `enableSessionState="true"` and `<sessionState timeout="30" />` in web.config.

It's driving me nuts!

**Update:** I refresh the page by hitting F5. Based on answers this should not cause a postback. I'd like to know when a use refreshes the page (even manually) and prevent some modifications to db).
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: do you have enableviewstate?set

Comment: When you say `refresh the page`, do you mean manually or actually by clicking on a server side control such as a button?

Comment: yes, i have set `enableViewstate` to true

Comment: I mean manually, by hitting F5

Comment: @Kamyar - Pressing F5 does not cause a postback, so there's nothing wrong with your code. (Check answers)

Comment: Sounds like you need some other mechanism to detect that the page was refreshed, like a counter.  Viewstate, Session, hidden field - there are many options.

Comment: Anyone can guide me how to know when the user refreshes the page manually? should I go throught referrer to find out?

Comment: @TheGeekYouNee: Thanks. Got it now. To whoever downvoted this... Care to share why?!!!

Comment: @Kamyar see the edit to my answer for a way to achieve this.

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman: Thanks. very thorough answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refreshing the page (pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or the refresh button in your browser) is not a postback.  A postback occurs when a button is clicked, a dropdown is changed, or some other event on the page that causes data to be sent to the server (via HTTP POST, hence the name 'postback')

<strike>Your question doesn't make it clear whether you are refreshing the page manually or posting back to the server via a button click or some other event.</strike>

Since you are manually refreshing the page, `IsPostBack` will always be false.

There are two types of requests (in a sense) in ASP.NET:

- a regular request (e.g. the user is loading the page for the first time)
- a postback (e.g. a button was clicked on the page, sending data to the server)

If you want to track if a user has been to a page before in either case, you'll need to track that your self.  You can set a variable in the Session to do this:

```
Session["UserHasVisitedThisPageBefore"] = true;
```

Then you can check it in place of your current `IsPostBack` check:

```
if(Session["UserHasVisitedThisPageBefore"] != null && (bool)Session["UserHasVisitedThisPageBefore"])
{
    // stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But using session state variables is not a good choice, since I have to remove it whenever user navigates aways from the page otherwise, If user goes to some other pages and comes back, it's still false. I think using hidden fields in the best choice for handling this.

Answer (score 5):

When you refresh the page, the `IsPostBack` should be false. It becomes true when a control has caused a postback, such as a server side button.

Edit - To answer your update:
You can use `IsPostBack` to determine whether or not you want to update the database. If it's false, don't update the database otherwise update it.

```
 if(IsPostBack)
 {
   //Update DB
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my problem was when the user refreshed the page, IsPostbBack was always false. Kyle's answer proposed I should use session variables. +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need some other mechanism to detect that the page was refreshed, like a counter. Viewstate, Session, hidden field - there are many options.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem of IsPostBack always being false in a particular project that had XSL rendering the markup.  So instead of relying on .NET's IsPostBack property, I simply checked Request.HttpMethod.

e.g. if I needed to check !IsPostBack, I instead checked if Request.HttpMethod == "GET"

e.g. if I needed to check IsPostBack, I instead checked if Request.HttpMethod == "POST"

Comment: Nice idea ... except my controls came back empty!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you refresh page you basically perform GET request to you page. GET means, load the page without any change of state server. `IsPostBack` = false is absolutely right behaviour!

The postback would occur on page, if you do POST to it. Then the server side form is being submitted or web control with `autoPostBack` is triggered - it would cause a postback. `IsPostBack` will be true.